# Get text/html from a DOM Object

Tags: javascript, dom

So I have my object that is:  iframe.contentDocument.body

I need put the html into a webservice  but the value is:

[object HTMLBodyElement]

I want :

```
<body>
   ...
</body>
```

Comment: iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML should give you what's inside <body> tag

Answer (score 0):

Use `Element.innerHTML` to get the html inside an html element as a string.
So to get the html of the iframe body tag, use `iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML`

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML